# Using Cobertura files for code coverage with SonarQube from Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I have a dot net core version: '3.0.100', building on 'Ubuntu 16.04' and am trying to get code coverage pushing to our self hosted SonarQube.

I have been using [Coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) to generate Cobertura files which can then use the PublishCodeCoverageResults@1 to publish to the Devops pipelines code coverage viewer.

I haven't been able to push the cobertura.xml file to sonarqube though.

I've read [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/) and it seems to me that the only mention of cobertura is with python and flex. Is it possible to use that file to cover my C# project?

I've been playing around with the following, but suspect what I have in extraProperties is incorrect.

```
- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'My SonarQube'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: 'dcap'
    projectName: 'DCAP'
    extraProperties: 'sonar.flex.cobertura.reportPaths=**/DCAP.Testing.Unit/TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to use that file to cover my C# project?

I am afraid there is no such out of box property to cover `C#` project with `Cobertura` format.

Just as you read, the cobertura is for python and flex. For the C#, we need to use the `sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths` or `sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths` with the format `dotCover` or `OpenCover`.

To resolve this issue, you could try to use a custom powershell script provided by Chameera Dulanga as workaround:

```
$Env:DOTNET_ROOT= (Get-Command dotnet).Path.Replace('dotnet.exe','sdk\2.1.300')
dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path . --version 4.0.12
dotnet tool install coverlet.console --tool-path . --version 1.4.1
mkdir .\reports
$testDll = gci -Recurse | ?{ $_.FullName -like ("*bin\{0}\{1}" -f "$(BuildConfiguration)", "$(TestDllFile)") }
$coverlet = "$pwd\coverlet.exe"
& $coverlet $testDll.FullName --target "dotnet" --targetargs ("vstest {0} --logger:trx" -f $testDll.FullName) --format "cobertura"
gci -Recurse |
?{ $_.Name -eq "coverage.cobertura.xml"} |
%{ &"$pwd\reportgenerator.exe" ("-reports:{0}" -f $_.FullName) "-targetdir:reports" "-reportstypes:HTMLInline;HTMLChart" }
```

You could check his blog [Running ASP.NET NUnit Tests in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline and Publishing Results to Sonar Cloud (LINK BROKEN)](https://medium.com/@chameeradulanga87/running-asp-net-nunit-tests-in-azure-devops-build-pipeline-and-publishing-results-to-sonar-cloud-20d14dccf275) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Damn Microsoft.  This is rubbish.  Code Coverage Tab in Azure DevOps when run on Linux using Coverlet REQUIRES cobertura XML. But to also get the coverage to work with SonarQube REQUIRES OpenCover.  Fix this ridiculousness.  Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 21):

I think the easiest solution is to configure coverlet to output multiple formats (see [documentation](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/VSTestIntegration.md)).

For local testing, this will generate the opencover format for SonarQube and the cobertura format for Azure DevOps:

```bash
# >= dotnet 7
dotnet test --collect "XPlat Code Coverage;Format=cobertura,opencover"
# < dotnet 6
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura,opencover
```

For integrating into your Azure Pipeline

```yaml
...
- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: Prepare SonarQube
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarQube Enterprise'
    projectKey: $(ProjectKey)
    projectName: $(ProjectName)
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/*.trx
      sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/*/coverage.opencover.xml
...
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage;Format=cobertura,opencover"
```

Comment: +1 for this solution, worked for me. Needed Coverdura for publishing code coverage results in Devops, but also needed code coverage to show in SonarCloud (which doesnt accept coverdura easily). So just did both like the answer above. Used the opencover xml for SonarCloud, and the coverdura xml for the Devops PublishCodeCoverageResults@1 step. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to point out that `dotnet test --collect "XPlat Code Coverage;Format=cobertura,opencover"` is good for .NET 6 and up.

Comment: Easiest solution I've found for .NET7. I got my test coverage published on Sonar and Azure that way.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Been trying to figure out how to generate these files way longer than I care to admit. Finally got the coverage posting. Appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use [MSBUILD Escaping](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2999) to tell coverlet to emit both cobertura and opencover result files on the one execution of the unit test suite.

With two files you can publish the cobertura one for Azure DevOps code coverage tab and give the opencover one via extraProperties to SonarQubePrepare.

Here is an extract of the important bits from my pipeline.

```
variables:
  APEX_SOLUTION: 'Redacted.sln'
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: 'Release'
  ARTIFACTORY_ROOT: 'Artifactory'
  REPOSITORY_CODE: 'redacted-generic-local'
  PRODUCT_PREFIX: 'BLAH'
  REPOSITORY_GROUP: 'Some/Path'
  REPOSITORY_APPLICATION: 'REDACTED'
  PUBLISH_FOLDER: 'publish'
  PACKAGING_FOLDER: 'packaging'
  COBERTURA_OUTPUT: 'coverage.cobertura.xml'
  OPENCOVER_OUTPUT: 'coverage.opencover.xml'
  IS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')]
  SONAR_SERVER_ENDPOINT: 'SonarQube'
  SONAR_PROJECT_KEY: 'redacted-web'
  SONAR_PROJECT_NAME: 'REDACTED-Web'
  .
  .
  .
- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
  inputs:
    SonarQube: $(SONAR_SERVER_ENDPOINT)
    scannerMode: MSBuild
    configMode: manual
    projectKey: $(SONAR_PROJECT_KEY)
    projectName: $(SONAR_PROJECT_NAME)
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/$(OPENCOVER_OUTPUT)"
      sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/TestResult.xml"
      sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true
      sonar.exclusions=Redacted/wwwroot/**
      sonar.branch.name=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
      sonar.projectVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)
  .
  .
  .
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(APEX_SOLUTION)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BUILD_CONFIGURATION) --logger "nunit;LogFilePath=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/TestResult.xml" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat="cobertura%2copencover" /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/ /p:Threshold=50 /p:ThresholdType=branch /p:ThresholdStat=Average /p:Exclude="[Redacted.Views]*"'
    publishTestResults: true

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
      summaryFileLocation: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/$(COBERTURA_OUTPUT)"
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on something else at the minute but should be back with this project in a couple of months. I'll have a look then.